# AppCompatButton get background color (colorButtonNormal/colorAccent) in code (Lollipop v21+)

Tags: android, xamarin

I've got code that iterates over views, after inflation, so I can hotswap certain colors.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is reading the current color used by, for example, a AppCompatButton runtime. I know that it's being colored by my AccentColor in some cases, but I don't know where to find that color programmatically on the View.

I've been using reflection and checking the private fields of the RippleDrawable (AppCompatButton.Background) and its children. But I'm coming up blank. I can't find the color and ColorStateLists are empty, Tints are null, Paint objects have White as the current color, etc.

I've been going over the Android source code on GitHub but I haven't found the solution yet, any help would be appreciated.

To clarify, I know what colors are being used, but I need to check if a specific AppCompatButton is using a specific color or not.

**Update 1**
It appears that the following two xml defines the AppCompatButton:
[btn_default_material.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6dfa60f33ca6018959ebff1efde82db7d2aed1e3/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_material.xml)
[btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6dfa60f33ca6018959ebff1efde82db7d2aed1e3/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml)

The second xml defines a shape with a android:tint="?attr/colorButtonNormal", that would be the GradientDrawable I was trying to extract information from.

I'll give it another go tomorrow and see if I can't extract the tint from the GradientDrawable...

Answer (score 0):

I found the color, in my specific case and Android OS version. It was mColor, inside mTintFilter, inside the GradientDrawable.

Hierarchy: AppCompatButton.Background.GetDrawable(0).Drawable.mTintFilter.mColor